# displaying information from a table to a registered userid or username MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my mysql database, UserReg and usernotes. Im trying to display the information from table usernotes for a particular username and userid. I was able to display the information from database, but it was showing up for every single user in the system instead of for the one who's information is that. I am working with dreamweaver server behaviors and I am not sure how to display information for just one user that the information belongs too. Both tables have UserName and UserID. Is it possible to just make user_id 7 to see information added for user_id 7? Please help!

```
<?php require_once('Connections/dbconnection.php'); ?>
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

// ** Logout the current user. **
$logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

  $logoutGoTo = "index.php";
  if ($logoutGoTo) {
    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "0,1";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "false";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && false) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_dbconnection, $dbconnection);
$query_Recordset1 = "SELECT UserReg.UserID,UserReg.UserName,usernotes.UserID,usernotes.UserName,usernotes.Homework,usernotes.Notes,usernotes.Grades,usernotes.classphotos FROM UserReg,usernotes WHERE UserReg.UserID = usernotes.UserID AND UserReg.UserName = usernotes.UserName ORDER BY UserReg.UserName = usernotes.UserName";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $dbconnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little unreadable for me, so I explain only the logic to you ;)

Once a user has logged in, you (your php script) has (must have) user's id (saved to user's session when he did authorized). Now, if user is trying access, for example

```
page.php?item_id=7
```

In your script you must do:

1. Load data from the database
2. Check if user_id of the loaded data equals to user_id of logged in use
3. If they equals, show data to him. If not - show "access denied" message to him

Comment: I am completely aware of logic :) I know exactly how to map it out, the only thing is missing how to check the session in this code that user_id = $_Session and $_Session = user_id.

Comment: When user log in, set $session['user_id'] = $user->id;

Comment: I tried many options on the code but nothing worked... Would you explain me where you would put it?